# How can I make React Native use the Xcode legacy build system?

Tags: ios, xcode, react-native, build, legacy-build-system

I'm kind of new to IOS development and especially Xcode, I can't manage to find a solution to my problem, so I hope someone here will be able to help me.

Until now I managed to build my react native app in both android and ios but now it's been a few days that I haven't been able to build the ios app anymore, because it uses the "new build system".

I know I have to use the legacy one, which I did previously and it worked fine. But now despite the fact that the "Use legacy build system" option is selected, it still uses the new one when I run "react-native run-ios", which causes several errors and fails the build.
[This is where I selected the Legacy Build System option](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wE4J2.png)

```
info Launching iPhone 11 (iOS 13.3)
info Building (using "xcodebuild -workspace App.xcworkspace -configuration Debug -scheme App -destination id=AA1BDEDE-F4B6-46B5-95EF-E0428BCE27B8 -derivedDataPath build/App")
....................................................................
error Failed to build iOS project. We ran "xcodebuild" command but it exited with error code 65. To debug build logs further, consider building your app with Xcode.app, by opening Drinky.xcworkspace. Run CLI with --verbose flag for more details.
User defaults from command line:
    IDEDerivedDataPathOverride = /Users/user/App/ios/build/App

note: Using new build system
note: Planning build
note: Constructing build description
Build system information
```

Comment: Could you try to run this command `xcodebuild -workspace App.xcworkspace -configuration Debug -scheme App -destination id=AA1BDEDE-F4B6-46B5-95EF-E0428BCE27B8 -derivedDataPath build/App -UseModernBuildSystem=NO` in your `ios/` folder please. Just to check that the problem is the build system.

Comment: @Théodvn Thanks for your comment, I already tried this and yes, the build is successful when using -UseModernBuildSystem=0
Unfortunately, I haven't found a solution to add this argument in combination with the react-native command.

Comment: Try This: run "react-native run-ios" and then open xcode and do the following: https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/19573, and after that run the app in a simulator through XCODE